# Incorrect syntax near 'BULK' for bulk INSERT in Azure Data Studio

Tags: sql-server, errors, mac-os-x, bulk-insert, azure-data-studio

I am trying to bulk insert a large CSV file delimited by tabs. I am on a Mac, and executing queries on Azure Data Studio (formerly SQL Operations Studio), since SSMS is not available for Macs. Here is the query:

```
BULK INSERT [kf].myTable
from '/Users/username/path/to/file.csv'
with(
    FIELDTERMINATOR = '\t',
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
```

The error I am getting is:

> Msg 103010, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 
>     Parse error at line: 1, column: 1: Incorrect syntax near 'BULK'

I've looked at other suggestions and none of them have worked. Is it possible that BULK is just not supported by Azure Data Studio?

Comment: Not that it solves your MAC issue, but I downloaded the Windows version of SQL Operations Studio and had no problems using your basic `BULK INSERT` command against a test table of mine.

Comment: ok. Is the file you are inserting local? and db remote? If yes, then maybe I can just use a windows computer instead to insert

Comment: Did you copy paste? any chance of weird characters in there?

Comment: Ive tried both copypaste and write from scratch. Same error. Any chance this has to do with the fact that the file to insert is stored in different location that db?